# Hook into angular-cli build watch

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'd like to to know if it is possible to hook into angular-cli's build/watch command:

> ng build /w

which generates files and drops them in the project's `/dist` folder

I just want after the build completes to copy the dist folder to another directory, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change the folder that it outputs to you can set that in the `angular-cli.json` file. There is an '`outdir`' setting in that you can change to be the folder you want it to output to.

Answer (score 16):

I managed to achieve what I wanted with parallel tasks, copyfiles and npm watch:

npm dev dependencies:

```json
"npm-watch": "^0.1.8",
"parallelshell": "^2.0.0",
"copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
```

package.json snippet:

```json
"watch": {
    "copy-files": "dist/*.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "watch": "npm-watch",
    "copy-files": "copyfiles src/** dist/** ../angular",
    "ng-build": "ng build -w",
    "build": "parallelshell \"ng build\" \"npm run watch\" "
  },
```

Then

> npm run build

FWIW the watch config is saying, if anything in dist/*.js changes, run the "copy-files" npm script...

Comment: Keep getting `directory not empty, rmdir '[...]\dist'` error from ng build when copyfiles runs close to build start or before build has completed. Only sure workaround I found was running 2 command line windows: one with `ng build --watch`, then once build has finished, another with `npm run watch`. This, instead of relying on parallelshell to do the same thing. Is there a single-command solution? Tried to add `timeout 20 &` before `npm run watch` in "build" package.json script, but that won't work with parallelshell (using Windows)

Comment: There are some other npm packages `npm-run-all` `concurrently` available to run tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to run `npm run build` and have a `postbuild` script that copies the content of index.html from your dist folder to your html/cshtml file in your desired folder and changes the script and link tag's paths in your newly copied file to point to the dist folder after the build it complete. Now run `ng build --watch` and start development.
I'm using `angular 6` and `angular-cli` with `.Net MVC 4.5` and I use `~\Views\Home` as my desired destination folder.

To have the watch mode running in my project I Run `npm run build:watch`
Now the watch mode works. Below is my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "build": "ng build",
        "build:watch": "npm run build && ng build --watch",
        "build:prod": "ng build --prod && npm run postbuild",
        "postbuild": "npm run copyindex && npm run fixpath",
        "copyindex": "copy /D \".\\dist\\index.html\" \"Views\\Home\\Index.cshtml\" /Y",
        "fixpath": "powershell -Command \"(gc Views\\Home\\Index.cshtml) -replace '(\\w+\\.js|\\w+\\.css)', '~/dist/$1' | Out-File Views\\Home\\Index.cshtml\"",
    },
```

**package.json explanation** :
after running `npm run build` the `postbuild` gets called automatically. `postbuild` will call `copyindex` and `fixpath` one after another.

- `copyindex` will copy the content of my `dist\index.html` to my `Views\Home\Index.cshtml`.
- `fixpath` will add `~/dist/` to the beginning of all *js* and *css* file paths in my `Index.cshtml`.
- `build:watch`: calls `ng build --watch`.
- `build:prod`: is for prod build and calls `ng build --prod` and `postbuild` one after another.

**Note**

- The commands can be run in any console on windows (cmd or bash).
- I used `powershell` in my `fixpath`. It can be replaced by your favorite tool.

Comment: is there any way to have postbuild run in --watch mode after every rebuild?

Comment: @Balage you can use "npm run build:watch" which run npm build first, it will copy the index.html to index.cshtml then it will watch the changes, whenever you change some thing in index.html, you need to run this command again.

Answer (score 2):

You should create your own node build script which calls the `ng build` command and after that copies the files to a directory:

```
let thread = exec('ng build -e=prod --prod', { maxBuffer: 1024 * 5000});
thread.on('close', (data) => {
    //do your moving stuff here
});
```

There is no way to hook into the `cli` (yet), and I don't think they will allow it. As far as I remember, they like to keep things closed there, because this way they are able to change/tune/update the build process a lot, without older builds going haywire

Comment: is there a way to hook into the --watch builds with your solution? maybe if you set npm-watch to watch your entire src folder and then trigger a full ng re-build every time a file changes? that would be clumsy

Answer (score -1):

Those looking for solution in angular 6+

In angular.json

```
in "build" --> options --> "outputPath":"your_path"
```