# MEAN with Angular 4 stack folder structure

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I want to create a folder structure for a MEAN stack with Angular 4.

I worked on MEAN stack with Angular 1.* version and Im good with that folder structure. but with Angular 4 - Angular Cli folder structure My model not working.

I'm planning for enterprise admin panel, so modules should be reusable and loosely coupled.

I tried one way : Keeping Client, Server and Test folder in Angular components. but which disturbing angular -cli component model.

Answer (score 3):

Use Angular CLI that ships with Angular 4. It itself generates a folder structure that helps manage your project in a modular manner with loosely coupled components.

Check https://cli.angular.io/

Use the angular folder structure for the front end and have a separate directory on top of angular project for back-end. For Node back end check for popular yeoman generators which would suit your application.

http://yeoman.io/generators/

- Your-application

  - Node-api
  - Angular-app

I propose a folder structure like this. But there may be better ones. Some research would help find such.

It is better if you can maintain two separate repositories for Node-api and Angular-app since it would help you maintain and manage them in a better way.

Comment: Thanks. After some more research, I feel separating repositories for node-api and Angular-app make more scene.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into this answer: [Hooking up express.js with Angular CLI in dev environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895585/hooking-up-express-js-with-angular-cli-in-dev-environment)

Basically you will have to separate server and client side code, otherwise you will end up having challenges at each step.

You can have a look at my code: https://github.com/kubaszumiato/DotNetVideos, where *app* folder stands for server, *src* for client. I am not using Angular CLI there though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular-cli for creating angualr 4 project. You can create Two folders Client,Server
Client- You can create project under this directory with angular-cli
Server - Use Node js server side code