# Integrated Angular (4) with Sails.js app, how to run Ahead-of-Time Compilation?

Tags: angular, sails.js

I have integrated Angular4 with sails.js app.   Everything works as expected.  However, I can't figure out how to run a Ahead-of-Time Compilation.

I am using commonJS my module loader, it is a very similar setup as to how they have it at this link, https://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html.

Does anyone know how to run a Ahead-of-Time Compilation for none Angular CLI?

Comment: my 2 cents. Stick with angular cli. Develop frontend (angular 4) and backend (sails) separately.  Merge both during deployment, by pushing the build output of angular into the public folder of sails (static assets)

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents. Stick with angular cli. Develop frontend (angular 4) and backend (sails) separately. Merge both during deployment, by pushing the build output of angular into the public folder of sails (static assets)

For more info, check the related question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907043/515774

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'll separate my project into sails.js and Angular CLI.