# Run Express service and Angular 6 app in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, angular, express

I am currently working on creating a CRUD app using [Angular6](https://appdividend.com/2018/05/27/angular-6-crud-example-mean-stack-tutorial/) with MSSQL.

I have successfully retrieved data from my local database and created the desired routes but I am having trouble displaying the data in the frontend.

```js
//masterList.service.ts

import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  MasterList
} from './MasterList';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MasterListService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:4000/masterList';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMasterList() {
    console.log(this);
    return this
      .http
      .get(`${this.uri}/`);
  }
}
//package.json

"name": "ng6crud",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "nodemon server.js && ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Running:

`npm start`

This returns the service with the data but the app is not compiled, and reversing the order does the opposite, with the error:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:4000/masterList/", ok: false, …}
```

**How do I get data from my service: `4000` and have it published: `4200` at the same time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing a number of steps to get this to work, most important being using **[concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859925/7626277)** which allowed both ports to run

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

//proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/masterList": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4000",
    "secure": true, //or false when cors is not in use with express
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}

//package.json

"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run serve-api\" \"npm run serve\"",
  "serve": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
  "serve-api": "nodemon server.js --watch server",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test"...
}

//service.ts
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  MasterList
} from './MasterList';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MasterListService {

  uri = '/masterList';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMasterList() {
    return this
      .http
      .get(`${this.uri}`);
  }

}
```

Comment: `concurrently` looks like a very interesting option. How should I structure the project? I started with an angular application. Do I create a top-level sub-folder called `/server` and then maintain a separate node.js project for the server within that folder?

Answer (score 4):

If you have your **server hosted on port 4000**, you need to **specify proxy** for your angular app so it will **redirect all api** calls **to port 4000**, even if it's hosted on port 4200.
Add **proxy.conf.json** next to your **package.json**:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

in **MasterListService** do something like:

```
getMasterList() {
  return this
    .http
    .get(`/masterList`);
}
```

and finally change your **package.json npm** start script:

```
...
"scripts": {
   ...
   "start": "nodemon server.js && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I wasn't really sure what I needed to resolve this, but your answer definitely got me on the right track! Thanks!