# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. how to fix it?

Tags: angular, servlets

I use Jersey RESTful Web as a server and want to communicate with angular.
Each HTTP request I try to send creates the following problem:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/login?password=1234&loginType=ADMIN&userName=admin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know the problem is that anguler and web service projects are in the same local host, but I know it has a solution..

I would be happy for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your angular app and your server app **are hosted on different origins**, to fix this you need to host them **on one origin** ([locally you can use proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469685/10971586)), or you need to enable [CORS on your web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/10971586). Hope that helps.