# Angular as Express Subapp

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I've recently started a new Web project using the MEAN Stack for the first time.

I have structured my project into express subapps (API, main page, admin panel) each in a separate subfolder. A main app.js `use(...)` all of the subapps for the given route.

Now, I would like to use angular for one of the subapps, ideally leaving everything else untouched.

However, I don't know what's the best / typical approach for this case.

As I understand it, I could write a standalone angular app (using the angular app template) in a subfolder and, after building, just serve the files in `dist/` as static files using express.

But I think there must be a better way to do this. So my question is what's the typical way to structure, setup and serve such kind of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching here, I found the following thread which basically covers everything I need to know. If there is some better way to combine them, I'm open to further ideas.

[Hooking up express.js with Angular CLI in dev environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895585/hooking-up-express-js-with-angular-cli-in-dev-environment)