# Run script after every build (serve or build prod) in Ionic4 (or Angular8+)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there a way to hook an extra script that will look into an specific `JSON` file and create an `enum` from it.

I need to recreate it after each change of the `JSON`. Usually I would use an npm watch for it but I want to hook it into the regular ionic/angular build, so if I run `ionic serve` or `ionic build` it should be called.

Is there a way to do this? I have found info about `pre` and `post` npm scripts but they just work for one call of scripts from the `package.json`

Writing an pre/post script after the angular build script `"build": "ng build",` does nothing while on `serve` mode.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis I have trying to put a `pre` or `post` script after the `    "build": "ng build"` script with an echo msg and it did not wrote anything in the console.

Comment: Does chanining `npm` scripts not work for you? You can create 1 script that creates the enum and then call another one like `ionic serve`, using `&&`. Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172536/running-npm-scripts-sequentially/39172660

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis for that `ionic serve` should end. It (like `ng serve`) lives in watch mode until I manually kill it with`ctrl+c`

Comment: You can create your own command inside `package.json` and `scripts` tag then use && to combine both

Comment: @distante You mean you want your enum creation script to run while `ionic serve` is active? Meaning make changes to the code -> save -> re-create enum -> reload browser? Something like that?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Yes exactly.  Currently I have to (remember to) run the script manually when I change the JSON file. I want to be able to let it automatically if possible.

Comment: @distante This works for `ng`, it might help you for ionic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364234/hook-into-angular-cli-build-watch

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis I already saw that post I thought that maybe angular has now some kind of hook system but looks like don't.